# How to ignore certain tag from svn to git migration

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have standard SVN layout. I am doing migration from SVN to git on Windows.

Following is command i am using.

```
git svn clone --stdlayout <svn-repo-url>
```

I want to ignore certain tags whose folder name has ":" or colon special character using `--ignore-path`.

i tried to edit/update config, but still its tries to fetch all branches and tags.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn-url
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = branches/{branch_a}:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tags = tags/{tag_a}:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

i just wanted to get branch_a and tag_a
Please help, dont downvote as i am not able to understand it.

Comment: I am saying, i am not able to ignore, still people downvote. If you know answer please comment.

Comment: You don't have any effect of --ignore-path in your config file. Maybe you should post what commands you tried already that failed to do what you expect.

Comment: @Vampire http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573531/java-projects-within-branch-treated-as-separated-branch-or-tags-in-git-from-svn

Comment: Find a way to use `svn2git` from my answer or you will have a really hard time to get a sensible history out of that mess. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

You can easily configure the tool with its rules file to make exactly what you want, including ignoring of certain tags.

---

Even though git-svn is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: i cant install svn2git for some reasons/policy :(

Comment: Too bad for you :-(