# Java projects within branch treated as separated branch or tags in git from svn?

Tags: git, svn

I am migrating to Git from SVN. We have following structure for any repository in SVN:

```
-trunk
    -javaproject1
    -javaproject2
-branch
    -branch1
        -javaproject1
        -javaproject2
    -branch2
        -javaproject1
        -javaproject2   
-tags
    -tag1
        -javaproject1
        -javaproject2
    -tag2
        -javaproject1
        -javaproject2
```

as a part of migration, i will have to migrate only `tag1` and `branch1` so i used following command in order.

```
git svn init <svn-repo-url>
```

This creates `.git` i go and change config created with following contents

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = <repo-svn-url>
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = branches/branch1/*:refs/remotes/origin/branch1/*
    tags = tags/tag1/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/tag1/*
```

Ran `git svn fetch`
Migration was completed but it has so many branches:

```
origin/branch1_javaproject_1
origin/branch1_javaproject_2
origin/tag1_javaproject_1
origin/tag1_javaproject_2
origin/master
```

Ideally it should be

```
 origin/branch1
    origin/tag1
    origin/master
```

Master was created properly with both java projects inside it, whereas tags nad branches are created per java project within it.

Answer (score 0):

```
branches = branches/branch1/*:refs/remotes/origin/branch1/*
tags = tags/tag1/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/tag1/*
```

these two look rather wrong. If `branch1` is a branch and `tag1` is a tag, they should be

```
branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/branches/*
tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it, by twitching config again as follows

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn-repo-url
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
    branches = branches/{branch1}:refs/remotes/origin/*
    tags = tags/{tag1}:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```